# DisplayMemberPath on certain click only

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

in Search_Click the source of lstBox is `List<string>` in btnStats_Click the source of lstBox il `List<Genre>`

after I have added DisplayMemberPath="Name" as listBox property, the Search_Click does not output anything.

Is the a way to apply DisplayMemberPath="Name" to lstBox, only on  btnStats_Click ?

```
public class Genre
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public string Drive { get; set; }
}

private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = Constants.allMoviesPath;

    var ext = new List<string> { @".txt", @".ini", @".exe", @".mob", @".srt", @".ass" };

    lstBox.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + SearchString + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => !ext.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f)))
               .Select(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
               .ToList();
}

private void btnStats_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lstBox.ItemsSource = FileLists.MoviesCountSizeStats();
}
```

return type of MoviesCountSizeStats() is `List<Genre>`

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="lstBox"
    Background="CadetBlue"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    FontSize="14"
    FontWeight="DemiBold"
    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}"
    MouseDoubleClick="lstBox_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

Comment: Please explain what this means: "several buttons produce output to the listBox, but only one button is tied to a class."  That makes no sense. Code would make sense.

Comment: Yes, I should have made it more clear. One button uses a class List<Genre>, other buttons use List<String>. So  DisplayMemberPath="Name" is used for the List<Genre>. But after I have added that property, the outputs for List<String> is not shown any more. And my question is how can I use  DisplayMemberPath="Name" conditionally, only for the button that uses List<Genre>?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I get it now. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. If you want to change `lstBox.DisplayMemberPath`... just change it.

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = Constants.allMoviesPath;

    var ext = new List<string> { @".txt", @".ini", @".exe", @".mob", @".srt", @".ass" };

    lstBox.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + SearchString + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => !ext.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f)))
               .Select(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
               .ToList();

    //  Null when it should be null
    lstBox.DisplayMemberPath = null;
}

private void btnStats_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lstBox.ItemsSource = FileLists.MoviesCountSizeStats();


    //  "Name" when it should be "Name"
    lstBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
}
```